# Automatic Updating XML from SQL server

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to retrieve information from a SQL server and insert into a XML doc.
The problem is not retrieving the information itself, but I want it to be done automatically e.g. 4 times per hour.

What can I use to automate this process? I'm using C# .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

1) Schedule a job to execute every 15 minutes in SQL Server

2) Schedule a job to run every 15 minutes using windows task scheduler

3) Write a small service that executes your logic every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

build a windows service that runs the job every 15 minutes using a timer

Comment: If it needs to run every 15 minutes, using a service for that seems like overkill - just have a simple command-line tool and schedule it with Windows Task Scheduler. Debugging a command-line tool is just soo much simpler than a Windows service....